# If a type is defined as not instantiable in Oracle, can a table of that type be created?

Tags: oracle

If so, what is meant by not instantiable? If not, what other restrictions apply?

What is the advantage of declaring a method as not instantiable in a supertype? When is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#i454831):

> Types and methods can be declared NOT INSTANTIABLE when they are
>   created.
>
> If a type is not instantiable, you cannot instantiate instances of
>   that type. There are no constructors (default or user-defined) for it.
>   You might use this with types intended to serve solely as supertypes
>   from which specialized subtypes are instantiated.

I read that as "You can only instantiate such objects as part of a supertype."  So it sounds like it works just like an *abstract type* in Java.   Whether it's part of a table or not seems irrelevant.